# Como evaluar la condición de varios elementos de un arreglo?

Tags: java

No se si me explico; tengo un trabajo escolar donde debo hacer el juego de serpientes y escaleras.

En un arreglo tengo los datos de los jugadores que son el nick y la posicion inicial del juego que es 1.

cada vez que los jugadores tiran los dados cambian de posicion. use un "Do While" para el juego continue hasta que un jugador llegue ala posicion 100.

Mi problema es que no se como evaluar esa condicion.

Programa:

```
int respuesta;
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a SnakeGame\nIngrese la cantidad de jugadores: ");
    respuesta=lectura.nextInt();

    Jugador [] p=new Jugador[respuesta];

   for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese su nickname: ");
    String n=lectura.next();

    p[i]=new Jugador(n);
    String nick=p[i].getNick();
    byte posicion=p[i].getPosicion();

    System.out.println(p[i] + "\nposicion: "+ p[i].getPosicion()+"\n");
  }

//**Aqui quiero poner el DO**

   for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Jugador "+ p[i].getNick() + "\npresione cualquier tecla para lazar los dados");
    String dados=lectura.next();

    System.out.println("Avanzo de la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+ "\n");
    byte posicion=p[i].tirarDados();

    System.out.println("A la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+"\n");
  } **while("Aqui no se como evaluar los elementos del arreglo")**
```

Espero me explique. soy un novato en la programacion espero su ayuda :)

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

//**Aqui quiero poner el DO**

```
   for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Jugador "+ p[i].getNick() + "\npresione cualquier tecla para lazar los dados");
    String dados=lectura.next();

    System.out.println("Avanzo de la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+ "\n");
    byte posicion=p[i].tirarDados();

    System.out.println("A la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+"\n");
    **if(p[i].getPosicion() = 100) String nick_ganador=p[i].getNick();**
  } **while(p[i].getPosicion() != 100)**`
 System.out.println("Ganador: " +nick_ganador+"\n");
```

No entendí muy bien tu pregunta, pero prueba con esta condición

Comment: El problema no esta en identificar al ganador del juego. el problema es que el juego continue mientras el jugador no llegue a la casilla 100.

cuando pongo while(p[i].getPosicion()!=100) no me reconoce el indice i pues esta dentro del for.

Entonces como hago para que evalue la posicion de todos los jugadores?

Gracias por responder.

Comment: int i = -1;
do{
    i++;
   if(i == p.length) i = 0;
    System.out.println("Jugador "+ p[i].getNick() + "\npresione cualquier tecla para lazar los dados");
    String dados=lectura.next();

    System.out.println("Avanzo de la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+ "\n");
    byte posicion=p[i].tirarDados();

    System.out.println("A la posicion: " +p[i].getPosicion()+"\n");
  } **while(p[i].getPosicion() != 100)**

Comment: uff !! muchisimas gracias jaja